# 3134 run time error on Insert into statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to write a form to insert data into multiple tables within a single database.

I know you can't do that through a single `Insert into` statement so I read that I should create a `transaction` and include multiple Insert statements. I keep getting `3134 run time error` on my second insert statement. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

    DBEngine.BeginTrans
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT into Names(StudentId, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName) VALUES (" & Me.txtStudentId & ",'" & _
        Me.txtFirstName & "','" & Me.txtMiddleName & "','" & Me.txtLastName & "')"
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT into Homeroom(StudentId, Grade, Homeroom_Primary, Name-Homeroom_Primary_Teacher) " & _
        "VALUES (" & Me.txtStudentId & ",'" & Me.txtGrade & "','" & Me.txtHomeroom & "','" & Me.txtTeacher & "')"
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT into [Ridgeview Math](StudentId, ExportGrade, DateTaken, SS, PR) VALUES (" & _
        Me.txtStudentId & ",'" & Me.txtGrade & "',#" & Me.txtMathdate & "#,'" & Me.txtMathSS & "','" & Me.txtMathPR & "')"
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT into [Ridgeview Reading](StudentId, ExportGrade, DateTaken, RSS, RPR, RIRL) " & _
        "VALUES (" & Me.txtStudentId & "','" & Me.txtGrade & "',#" & Me.txtReadingdate & "#,'" & Me.txtReadingSS & "','" & _
        Me.txtReadingPR & "','" & Me.txtReadingIRL & "')"
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT into CompassGroup(StudentId, CompassGroup) VALUES (" & Me.txtStudentId & _
        "," & Me.txtCompassGroup & ")"
    DBEngine.CommitTrans

End Sub
```

Am I doing something wrong with the nested Insert statements?

This is all tied to a form where the variables are created and the data is entered. The first Insert statement gives me no errors. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Is "Name-Homeroom_Primary_Teacher" really a column name?

Answer (score 2):

Bracket the field name *Name-Homeroom_Primary_Teacher* because of the dash.

I suggest you use a string variable to hold the statement text, `Debug.Print` the string, and then `Execute` it.

```vb
Dim strInsert As String
strInsert = "INSERT into Homeroom(StudentId, Grade, Homeroom_Primary, [Name-Homeroom_Primary_Teacher]) " & _
        "VALUES (" & Me.txtStudentId & ",'" & Me.txtGrade & "','" & Me.txtHomeroom & "','" & Me.txtTeacher & "')"
Debug.Print strInsert
CurrentDb.Execute strInsert, dbFailonerror
```

If case of errors, you can go to the Immediate window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>) to inspect the statement text.  And you can copy that text, create a new query in the query designer, switch to SQL View, paste in the text, and test the statement there.

Also the approach you're using requires a whole lot of concatenating.  Other options you can consider are: parameter queries; adding rows to `DAO Recordsets`.

Comment: +1 for recommending parameter queries or recordset updates. Without them Ms. O'Connor and her students are going to be a bit of a nuisance.